# Intellij, how to use a .class(without source code) in my own project

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

Due to a suggestion I have decided to add the whole project to github, so it's easier for experts to help me :/. I've been googling around for hours and can't seem to fix it. https://github.com/NicholasExxonite/test_lab_week13

Alright. So this is from a lab class, we where given an archive with 2 .java files, one is Ball and another Triangle(they contain the class and methods to create the shapes) and 5 .class files called GameArena(the purpose of being it only a .class file and not the whole source code is so that we cannot change it).
I need to create a main class and create instances of these classes and call their methods to create a working game. The triangle and ball .java files are okay, I can access them and call them. However my intellij just doesn't want to recognise GameArena.class.
 The contents of the given archive : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4umHY.jpg

I am a new java/intelliJ user running the 2018.2.7(build 182.5107.41)version with SDK 11.0.2. I decompressed the archive in my project's source folder, from then Ball and Triangle were usable, but GameArena not. So I tried adding it's path from Files-Project Structure-Modules, then I tried to add it to classpath in the platform setting.
None of them work, when I try to build and run the main method I get the following error:

```
Error:(4, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GameArena
  location: class testGame
Error:(4, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GameArena
  location: class testGame
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6W5F.jpg

```
public class testGame {
    public static void main (String Args[]){
        Ball newBall = new Ball(100, 100, 50, "Yellow");
        GameArena newGame = new GameArena(200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the package of GameArena class? Note that you can't import the classes from the default package (Java limitation). If unsure, share the project to that others can see what's the problem and suggest the proper configuration.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. I have uploaded the whole project to github. I've been googling around for hours and couldn't get it to work. https://github.com/NicholasExxonite/test_lab_week13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

**1. Copy your Gamearena Class files to a new Directory**

- Right Click on your test_lab_week13
- new Directory 'Libs'
- Copy all your .class files for Gamearena to Libs (simply per drag&drop)

[image]

**2. Add your Libs directory as dependency to your module**

- Files > Project Structure... (Ctrl + Alt + + Shift + S)
- Set Project SDK to Oracle JDK 1.8 (11 will not work, because it doesnt support JavaFX)

[image]

- Add Lib Directory to your module dependency, by selecting Dependencies tab and add with +

[image]

**3. Build your Project and start it**

- Build > Build Project (Ctrl + F9)
- Run > Run testgame

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yep it worked! Thank you. I had tried that a lot of times adding different dependencies, classpaths, sourcepaths, libs and so one, but it always ended up with some error or another. 
The problem was the the SDK. Changing it to JDK 1.8 fixed all my problems for the past hours.